# We suppose: $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $a$ then $b+c$ is a multiple of $a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Are those statements true?

We suppose: $ a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$.

- We suppose: $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $a$ then $b+c$ is a multiple of $a$.
- We suppose: $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $a$ and $(b > c)$ then $b-c$ is a multiple of $a$.
- We suppose: $b$ is a multiple of $a$ then $b \cdot c$ is a multiple of $a$.

I think only the last one is correct, I proved it, but how to prove that the others are wrong other than contradicting examples? (are they wrong first?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all correct. For the first one, if $b$ is a multiple of $a$, then there is an integer $k$ for which $b = ka$. Likewise, $c = ma$. Hence

$$b + c = ka + ma = a(k + m)$$

is a multiple of $a$. The second point is proved similarly.

Comment: I thought it was $a=bk$ and $a=cm$ ^^
Thanks!